# ODBCでオラクルサーバーへ接続する際にエラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

初めての質問です。
ＥＸＣＥＬＶＢＡを使用し、オラクルサーバに接続する際にエラーコード3076「アプリケーション定義またはオブジェクトの定義エラー」が出てしまいます。
エラーを解消する方法をいくつか試してみたのですが上手くいきませんでした。
お仕事の関係で最近ＥＸＣＥＬＶＢＡを勉強し始めたのですが、私の周りに詳しい方がおりませんでしたので質問させていただきました。

データベース：oracle11g
エクセル:Microsoft Excel 2010

（行った対処法）
参照設定を変更：Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.X Libraryにチェックを入れました。
インストーラーでORACLE PROVIDER FOR OLE DBを追加インストールしました。

以上です。対処法がわかる方、アドバイスをお願いします。

```
Sub test()
 Dim cn As Object
 Dim conStr As String
 Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 conStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB;Data Source=サーバ名;User ID=ユーザー名;Password=パスワード"
cn.Open conStr
 End Sub
```

Comment: Oracle Clientはインストールしてますか？

Comment: Ｏｒａｃｌｅ　Ｃｌｉｅｎｔはインストール済みです。

Answer (score 1):

手元のExcel 2010 + Oracle 11g Client環境で試したところ同一のエラーが出ましたが、以下の箇所を直したら動きました。
試してみてはいかがでしょうか。
※参照設定の変更は行っていません。

conStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB;...
↓
conStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;...

```
Sub test()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim conStr As String
    Dim rs As Object

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=TNSネットサービス名;User ID=ユーザー名;Password=パスワード"
    cn.Open conStr

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")       'レコードセット
    rs.Open "select * from USER_TABLES where rownum <= 3", cn
    Do Until rs.EOF
        MsgBox rs("TABLE_NAME").Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
End Sub
```